# "Word for word" or "word by word"?

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

I have an idiom that is used in a sentence; which is correct?

> - You are asked to copy this letter *word by word*.
> - You are asked to copy this letter *word for word*.

Which is correct?

Comment: What research have you done on the topic?  Have you looked up both idioms and compared their definitions yourself?

Comment: Yes i have word for word is verbatim where as word by word is single word

Comment: Then haven't you answered your own question?  If you mean *verbatim*, use *word for word*.  If you mean *each word, one by one*, use *word by word*.

Comment: I have mistakenly closevoted as General Reference. It's actually a duplicate of [*Is there any difference between “word-for-word translation” and “word-by-word translation” and is the latter actually valid?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169277/)

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "word by word" would mean one word at a time, sequentially. If you're copying something "word by word", it means you're doing it probably means you're doing it in the moment. "Word by word" describes iteration. For example:

> To ensure she hadn't missed anything, Stacy reread the page more slowly, word by word. Only when the full weight of each word set in did she continue to the next.
>
> As Jacob worked on his first try at the bar examination, he read every question word by word, repeating each word quietly to himself to be sure he didn't miss anything.

The phrase "word for word" can mean many things, all of which tie into the abstracted idea of transcription. Every word on the source is understood or copied to the destination. In the example posted in the question, "word for word" would be the correct phrase. "Word for word" describes the relationship between two sets of words. For example:

> Copy this paragraph word for word. Double check to make sure everything is *exactly* the same.
>
> I swear, that's what he said, word for word!

Sometimes either phrase can be used appropriately but will change the meaning of the sentence.

> Word by word, her spoken words appeared on the magical tablet.

This one means words are appearing one at a time, as the character speaks.

> Word for word, her spoken words appeared on the magical tablet.

This one means every single word she spoke appeared on the tablet, but it doesn't actually describe when or how those words appeared. Maybe she delivers a whole monologue, and as soon as she finishes, the tablet instantly updates with every single word she spoke, or maybe the words do appear one at a time, as she speaks them. Interpretation is up to the reader!

Answer (score -1):

"**Word for word**" is the correct idiom . It means that you are asked to copy this letter with the same words (as were originally used) .

Comment: *word by word* is a perfectly valid phrase, and means something distinct from *word for word*.